# Combine Plots of SageMath and Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, sage

How can I combine plots from Sage and Matplotlib into a single plot without one overlaying the other?

Here's an example script where I attempt to combine Sage and Matplotlib plots:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ax.plot(x, y)

c = circle((1,1),1)
c_matplotlib = c.matplotlib(figure=fig)  # this Returns matplotlib.figure.Figure object

plt.show()
```

However, when I run this script, Sage just puts another image on top of the canvas of Matplotlib. Is there a way to update the canvas of Matplotlib to combine the two plots into one?

### Image

[image]

### Reference

- Link to sage cell: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=uoezbs

Comment: According to [sagemath's matplotlib docs](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plotting/sage/plot/graphics.html#sage.plot.graphics.Graphics.matplotlib) you can use `c.matplotlib(figure=fig, sub=ax)` to plot onto a specific subplot. If no `sub` is given, a new one will be created.

Comment: Please don't add the answer inside the question's post. Instead, you can create an own answer and mark it as accepted. See [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

### Working Solution by JohanC

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ax.plot(x, y)
c = circle((1,1),1)
c_matplotlib = c.matplotlib(figure=fig, sub=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]